# java remove elements which match certain duplication rules from list

Tags: java

I have a list like this:

```
List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
Map<String, String> row;

row = new HashMap<String, String>();
row.put("page", "page1");
row.put("section", "section1");
row.put("index", "index1");
list.add(row);

row = new HashMap<String, String>();
row.put("page", "page2");
row.put("section", "section2");
row.put("index", "index2");
list.add(row);

row = new HashMap<String, String>();
row.put("page", "page3");
row.put("section", "section1");
row.put("index", "index1");
list.add(row);
```

I need to remove duplicates based on 2 out of 3 elements ("section", "index") of the row (Map) being the same. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
for (Map<String, String> row : list) {
    for (Map<String, String> el : list) {
        if (row.get("section").equals(el.get("section")) && row.get("index").equals(el.get("index"))) {
            list.remove(el);
        }
    }
}
```

it fails with `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`. There must be another way of doing this, but I don't know how. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** I've tried to use Iterator, as suggested, still the same exception:

```
Iterator<Map<String, String>> it = list.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map<String, String> row = it.next();
    for (Map<String, String> el : list) {
        if (row.get("section").equals(el.get("section")) && row.get("index").equals(el.get("index"))) {
            list.remove(row);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE2:** This fails with the same exception:

```
Iterator<Map<String, String>> it = list.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map<String, String> row = it.next();
    Iterator<Map<String, String>> innerIt = list.iterator();
    while (innerIt.hasNext()) {
        Map<String, String> el = innerIt.next();
        if (row.get("section").equals(el.get("section")) && row.get("index").equals(el.get("index"))) {
            innerIt.remove();
            //it.remove(); //fails as well
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 3, SOLUTION:** Annoyingly simple:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
        if (list.get(i).get("section").equals(list.get(j).get("section")) && list.get(i).get("index").equals(list.get(j).get("index"))) {
            list.remove(i);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 4:** "Solution" didn't work as intended. Correct answer is now selected.

Comment: For inner map, use iterator instead of `for-each`

Comment: Something no one else seems to have noted is that you could avoid the issue by using a normal for loop with an index variable, which avoids using an iterator. If you were to switch to an implementation other than `ArrayList`, though, that might pose performance problems.

Comment: haven't you tried my code.?

Comment: In your first Update you still remove an element in a for loop. It is expected to fail. In the second you use an iterator inside another iterator and I suggest you to avoid it. Try while(it.hasNext()) without declaring a new iterator.

Comment: With update 3, the code does not produce exception but the output is incorrect. it should contain 2 results but contains only one.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Thanks, I have noticed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot add/remove elements of collections while iterating on it, except if you iterate via an [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).

See [Collection#iterator()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#iterator%28%29) to get an iterator on your Map.

See [Iterator#remove()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29) to see how to remove elements from a Collection while iterating on it.

You can structure your code like this :

```
//Get an iterator on your list.
Iterator<Map<String, String>> itr = list.iterator();

//iterate
while(itr.hasNext()) {
  Map<String, String> elt= itr.next();
  if(isDuplicate(list, elt)) {
    itr.remove();
  }
}
```

Here is an example of method to find if you have a duplicate :

```
public boolean isDuplicate(List<Map<String, String>> list, Map<String, String> map){
  //Count the occurences of the searched element.
  int cpt = 0;

  /*
   * Here, another iterator is implicitly created.
   * It is not the same as in the main loop. 
   * That's why I avoid the ConcurrentModificationException.
   */
  for(Map<String, String> m : list) {
    if(m.get("section").equals(map.get("section")) && m.get("index").equals(map.get("index"))) {
      cpt++;
    }
  }
  //If the element is found twice, then it is a duplicate.
  return cpt == 2;
}
```

Here is an extract of Javadoc for method ArrayList#remove() (from Sun JDK sources) :

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException. Thus, in the face of concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.

To understand furtherly how iterators works, let's read the Sun JDK source for ArrayList iterators. This is an inner class found in ArrayList.java :

```
private class Itr implements Iterator<E> {
  int cursor;       // index of next element to return
  int lastRet = -1; // index of last element returned; -1 if no such
  int expectedModCount = modCount;
```

Here, we can see that when instantiated ( with Collection#iterator() ), the iterator initializes a `expectedModCount` (modCount = modification count). Here, `modCount` is an attribute of the class ArrayList.

Each time you call a method on the iterator (`next()`, `previous()`, `add()`, `remove()`), this method is called :

```
final void checkForComodification() {
  if (modCount != expectedModCount)
    throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
}
```

This is the method that throws **ConcurrentModificationException**!

Each time you do a modification on a list, the ArrayList updates `modCount`. So if you modify a list without an iterator, `modCount` becomes != `expectedModCount`. At the next call of any method of the iterator, you get the exception.

When you use a for-each loop, you are implicitly creating an iterator and calling next() at the end of each loop.

Each time you modify the list via a method from the iterator, `expectedModCount` is updated to `modCount`, avoiding you the ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: I only see one loop here, but I also need an inner loop to find duplicates.

Comment: Arnaud's answer is good but partial. See my correct & complete answer which has both loops, doesn't need a copy and is optimally performant.

Comment: @Caballero : You must complete this part. I suggest you to do this check in another method. See the part `boolean conditionToRemove = ...`

Comment: @Caballero : Edited my answer to provide a `isDuplicate()` method.

Comment: @Arnaud Denoyelle I'm sorry, this still doesn't work. All you did is port the condition into a separate function but that achieves nothing, because it fails on `itr.remove()`

Comment: @Caballero : Are you sure? This code is tested and it works on my computer. Porting the condition in a separate method is useful because in this method, I implicitly create a new iterator (see the comments in the code). I put a `System.out.println(list);` at the end of my code and I tested. It works and the output is `[{index=index2, page=page2, section=section2}, {index=index1, page=page3, section=section1}]`. Can you re-test?

Answer (score 1):

If you use an Iterator explicitly, you can remove from it. You wouldn't be able to combine this with a 'foreach' loop or other iterator, *except in this case once you find a match the inner loop ends.*

[Note: I fixed the condition, as it didn't exclude self-matching.]

```
Iterator<Map<String,String>> outerIt = list.iterator();
while (outerIt.hasNext()) {
    Map<String,String> outer = outerIt.next();

    for (Map<String, String> inner : list) {
        if ((inner != outer) && outer.get("section").equals(inner.get("section")) && outer.get("index").equals(inner.get("index"))) {
            // Match;  de-dup.
            //   -- no longer iterating the 'inner' loop, so we don't need a copy.
            outerIt.remove();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

For situations where you can't precisely structure the inner iteration, it's simplest to copy the original list before the loop starts & just iterate the copy to guarantees stable & reliable iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a list of elements you wish to remove and remove them after.

```
List<Map<String, String> removeList = new List<Map<String, String>();
for (Map<String, String> row : list) 
    for (Map<String, String> el : list)
        if (row.get("section").equals(el.get("section")) && row.get("index").equals(el.get("index")))
            removeList.add( el );


 for( Map< String, String > i : removeList )
     list.remove( i );
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to make a copy of the HashMap you are trying to modify. Iterate over the copy and change the original one.

Try this...

```
Map<String, String> copyOfList = new HashMap<String, String>(list);

for (Map<String, String> row : copyOfList ) {
    for (Map<String, String> el : copyOfList ) {
        if (row.get("section").equals(el.get("section")) && row.get("index").equals(el.get("index"))) {
            list.remove(el);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the traditional for loop instead of using others.

```
   for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
    {

    for(int j=0;j<list.size();j++)
    {

     if (list.get(i).get("section").equals(list.get(j).get("section")) && list.get(i).get("index").equals(list.get(j).get("index"))) {

            list.remove(j);
            j -= 1 ;
      }

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple logic without using `loop` or `Iterator`,

- Add the list to a [Treeset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) with custom [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) (to compare based on your condition)
- Convert the [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) back to [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

You can achieve the same as below,

```
public static List<Map<String, String>> removeDuplicate(
        List<Map<String, String>> list) {

    Set<Map<String, String>> set = new TreeSet<Map<String, String>>(
            new Comparator<Map<String, String>>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Map<String, String> o1,
                        Map<String, String> o2) {

                    // Your equals condition
                    if (o1.get("section").equals(o2.get("section"))
                            && o1.get("index").equals(o2.get("index")))
                        return 0;
                    return -1;
                }
            });
    set.addAll(list);     
    // convert back to list and return 
    return new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>(set); 
}
```